# field weights across models with thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I have the following index file:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :publication, :with => :active_record do
  indexes taggings.tag.name, :as => :tags
  indexes transcript.transcript_text, :as => :transcript
end
```

And I try to run a search like so:

```
Publication.search("network | unblock", :field_weights => {:transcript => 100, :tags => 1})
```

But the results always prioritize tagging instead of transcript and put them first. I want it to perform the search it would normally run without a tag index, where it would put publications with both "network" and "unblock" in the transcript first and then the rest of the results after that. Tried several variations but can't come up with the desired behavior. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!